# extracting first character from each array element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I'm trying to extract the first character from each array element in Javascript, so I end up extracting the 1, the 4, the 7, the 2, the 5, and the 8, but I keep getting "extractElement is not a function" What am I doing wrong?

```
var characterArray = ['123','456','789','234','567','890'];

var extractElement;
var extractSlicedCharacter;

function extractEachFirstNumber(){
   for(counter = 0; counter <= characterArray.length; counter++){
      extractElement = characterArray[counter];
      extractSlicedCharacter = extractElement.slice(0,1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `<` not `<=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice returns an array, not a single character.  You should just use charAt.

```
var characterArray = ['123','456','789','234','567','890'];

var extractElement;
var extractSlicedCharacter;

function extractEachFirstNumber(){
   for(counter = 0; counter <= characterArray.length; counter++){
      extractElement = characterArray[counter];
alert(extractElement.charAt(1));
//extractSlicedCharacter = extractElement.charAt(1);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, except you should change your loop logic from `<=` to just `<`

```js
var characterArray = ['123','456','789','234','567','890'];

var extractElement;
var extractSlicedCharacter;

function extractEachFirstNumber(){
   for(counter = 0; counter < characterArray.length; counter++){
      extractElement = characterArray[counter];
      extractSlicedCharacter = extractElement.slice(0,1);
     console.log(extractSlicedCharacter);
   }
}
extractEachFirstNumber();
```

Comment: instead of slicing, you could characterArray[0][0], characterArray[1][0] and so on...

Comment: Or just replace `extractSlicedCharacter = extractElement.slice(0,1);` with `extractSlicedCharacter.push(extractElement.slice(0,1));` (and be sure to define `extractSlicedCharacter` as an array)

Answer (score 0):

@depperm answer should solve the problem

another way could be

```
var outputArray = [];
characterArray.forEach( function(element){
   outputArray.push( element.charAt(0) );
} );    
console.log( outputArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the below by conveniently using the [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
result = characterArray.map(function(el) {return el[0]})
//=> [ '1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '8' ]
```